# Origin of Java syntax for creating new instance of an inner class?

Tags: java, syntax, inner-classes

I'm curious as to the syntax choice for instantiating an inner class given an instance of the outer class in Java.

The syntax is:

```
OuterClass.InnerClass innerObject = outerObject.new InnerClass();
```

But why is it not:

```
OuterClass.InnerClass innerObject = new outerObject.InnerClass();
```

The former seems to imply that new is a method or operator directly associated with the class, but my understanding is that this is not the case (unlike C++)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The latter would imply to me that the *type* name was `outerObject.InnerClass` - whereas actually the typename is just `InnerClass` (or `OuterClass.InnerClass`, which would also be legal) constructed *with relation to* the instance referred to by `outerObject`.

Personally I don't like the way Java does nested classes in the first place, and I agree it looks a little bit odd, but I can see why it's done that way.

Answer (score 3):

There's another reason as well.

```
new o.C();
```

has two possible meanings.  It could mean the creation of an inner class `C` in the context of an outer object `o`.  It could also be the creation of an class whose fully qualified name is `o.C`.  This ambiguity is problematic, especially since both interpretations could be valid at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

The inner class is a subset of, in all ways an intrinsic part of the outer class. The inner class can access all of the outer class' members, as if they were one. Similarly, an instance of a (non-`static`) inner class must be an intrinsic part of an instance of the outer class. It cannot exist on its own. You could compare it to how you can't access a non-static variable or function with `MyClass.wyVariable`.

This raises the point of which way is the most semantically correct way of representing this relationship.

```
OuterClass.InnerClass innerObject = new outerObject.InnerClass();
```

... would (semantically) assert that `InnerClass` is somehow a property of `outerObject` which, once fetched, can be handled freely out in the world outside the scope of `outerObject`. `new` in this case would be nothing special.

Rather `InnerClass` is a part of `OuterClass` whereas an *instance* of `InnerClass` must a part of an *instance* of `OuterClass`.

The syntax above would symbolize that `InnerClass` (the class itself) is a part of some instance of `OuterClass`, which is semantically incorrect. There is after all only one class `InnerClass`, even if this class may have any number of instances.

```
OuterClass.InnerClass innerObject = new OuterClass.InnerClass();
```

... would of course also be (semantically) incorrect for non-`static` inner classes, as it in no way represents the special loving and caring relationship between the instances of the inner and outer class.

Note however, that this syntax is perfectly fine for `static` inner classes, as they have no special relationship to any one instance of the outer class. It's also perfectly fine when instantiating an inner class inside its outer class.

Finally,

```
OuterClass.InnerClass innerObject = outerObject.new InnerClass();
```

... symbolizes the relationship better. It symbolizes that the *process of instantiation* is uniquely tied to a single, specific outer object, which is the case.